# Why does "last" behave differently in Perl in these examples?

Tags: perl

This loop never stops:

```
while (1)
{
    while (1)
    {
        last;
    }
}
```

This loop stops

```
while (1)
{
    do
    {
        last;
    }
    while (1);
}
```

Without `last`, they are similar in their infinity.  The 2nd loop structure does not appear to consider the inner loop as a loop.  I presume in 2nd structure `last` actually exits the outer loop, before the inner loop begins.   But why?  Does the inner loop actually starts "later", after `do{}` has completed its first execution?

Comment: `perldoc -f do`:  "`do BLOCK` does not count as a loop, so the loop control statements `next`, `last`, or `redo` cannot be used to leave or restart the block. "

Comment: @ikegami - `perl -E 'say($_), last for 5 .. 10`

Comment: @JimDavis Interesting. `for` as a statement modifier has different semantics than `while`/`until` (`perl -e'last while 1'` gives `Can't "last" outside a loop block`). You can label a `for` statement modifier, but not a `while`: `perl -E'FOO:say, last FOO for 1..10`. Also compare the B::Concise output for `1 while 1`, `while (1) { 1 }`, `1 for 1`, and `{ 1 }`. All but `1 while 1` generate `leaveloop` opcodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`perldoc -f last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html):

> last cannot be used to exit a block that returns a value such as eval
>   {} , sub {} , or do {} , and should not be used to exit a grep() or
>   map() operation.

```
do {
   # ... 
} while (1);
```

is not actually a looping in Perl, so `last`, `next`, `redo` don't function properly inside of it.

A single block *is* in fact a loop though, so you can wrap your do expression in a block to allows `last` to function as you expect:

```
{
   do {
      last; 
   } while (1); 
}
```

A more intuitive solution would by to have a sentinel value that controls exectution:

```
my $should_stop = 0;
do {  
   if ( <some-condition> ) { $should_stop = 1; }
} while ( !$should_stop )
```

Comment: hmm, didn't realize this was a duplicate